# Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator in ViewModels not instantiated by CM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In my ShellViewModel I've got the following function which queries using Linq and EntityFramework. The goal here is to translate the POCO's to ViewModels and bind the resulting ViewModels to a ListBox in ShellView using CM.

Below is a partial listing of the code. Everything works fine. However, I'm now at a point where I need for each ItemViewModel to be able to notify ShellViewModel when a certain action happens. How can I get CM's EventAggregator into each ItemViewModel? All the EventAggregator examples show this happening through dependency injection via ViewModel's Ctor. How do I get dependency injection to work when instantiating ViewModels as shown in GetData() below?

```cs
[Export(typeof(ShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<UserPasswordChanged>
{
    private void GetData()
    {
        var query = _EfDataContext.Items
            .Where(x => (x.CreatedDtm > DayBeginning && x.CreatedDtm <= NowDtm));

        //Create a list of ItemViewModels for Caliburn.Micro to Bind
        //How can EventAggregator be injected into ItemViewModel when
        //creating ViewModels this way?

        this.Items = new BindableCollection<ItemViewModel>(query
                .Select(x => new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Item = x
                }));
    }
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
            IsDeveloperMode = false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass along your EventAggregator like so?

```
// ...
.Select(x => new ItemViewModel(_eventAggregator)
// ...
```

Since these are explicitly created by an instance that already has had the dependency injected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sven, when I tried this with object initialization syntax, I get the following error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Caliburn.Micro.IEventAggregator'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to reproduce that error message. I tried EventAggregator = this._event like you posted in your own answer, but that works fine. Is EventAggregator a property of IEventAggregator on ItemViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with my Linq statement. I had already tried to pass the event aggregator from the ShellViewModel to the ItemViewModel, since as Sven noted, the thing's already been injected. Why inject it again?

```
Items =
            new BindableCollection<ItemViewModel>(query
                .Select(x => new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Item = x,
                    EventAggregator = this._eventAggregator
                }));
```

However this results in the following error:
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Caliburn.Micro.IEventAggregator'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I hadn't realized at the time that this wasn't an issue with Mef or CM but with Linq. The following two-step solution works:

```
Items =
            new BindableCollection<ItemViewModel>(query
                .Select(x => new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Item = x
                }));

foreach (var itemViewModel in Items)
            itemViewModel .EventAggregator = this._eventAggregator;
```

Comment: you solve your problem? its a weird way of assigning EventAggregator by doing it outside the ViewModel itself.. you can just do it in the constructor e.g public ItemViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator){ this.EventAggregator = evenAggregator} and you dont new ItemViewModel instead let MVVM handle it